# Can't get SSL/TLS and node to play nice and connect to SMTP

Tags: javascript, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am trying to connect to an SMTP server using TLS to no avail.

I am trying to replicate the following using node: `openssl s_client -crlf -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587`

I've tried a multitude of different options and parameters but can't seem to get passed the following error:

`Error: 139731603597184:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:`

The following code works through port `465` (SMTPS) but I'm looking to connect via `587` (TLS/submission):

```js
const tls = require('tls'),
    port = 465,
    hostname = 'smtp.gmail.com';

const options = {
    port: port,
    host: hostname
};

const socket = tls.connect(options);

socket.setEncoding('utf8');

socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Server: ${data}`);
});

socket.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
});

socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log("End connection");
});
```

Am I missing an option in the tls section of the docs that is causing this error? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: STARTTLS is a specific beast, not a pure TLS handshake. See example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS  : you first start to discuss in **clear** and then only you switch to TLS. You do not start with TLS directly. So this will be fare more complicated to code.